# Stored Procedure runs slow when executed by DataFactory

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I've made a Stored Procedure which runs in 14 minuten in SQL server (on Azure DB, the data stays in the same database).

When this Stored Procedure is executed as a pipeline in Data Factory then it takes around 1 hour or more. And when I double the selected period SQL execution take around 30 minutes, but DF even gets a time-out after 4.5 hours.

I'm pretty sure that DF is only a tool, that would use the normal SQL engine so that the performance would be identical, but it's not. Somebody any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Does the stored procedure have parameters?  Do you supply different parameters to it when running via Management Studio versus Data Factory?

Comment: No, we don't use a parameter at all... It's really the same code that's executed

Comment: Hmm, strange.  I guess I would rule out the obvious, make sure you are connecting to the same server, check the SQL Server error logs for anything obvious (like transaction log full, out of disk space etc) then consider opening a support ticket.

Comment: No I don't think it's that kind of issues, because of that it happens day after day. And we're using Azure DB.

Comment: Do you have other pipelines and activities in the same data factory running at the same time?

Comment: Yes, sometimes. But then we can understand it, but when we have to rerun 1 pipeline because of this failure it also happens...

We now set concurreny to 1 and it works well (for now). But we still can't understand why it didn't work when a higher concurrency but while just executing 1 pipeline.....

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" comes a few years late, but I stumbled across this question when running into similar problems of my own. A stored procedure which took seconds to run via SSMS took around 20 minutes to complete when triggered (with the same parameters and work to do) via Azure Data Factory.

However, this slowness was only present when running my ADF pipeline via the Debug options. As soon as I ran it via a normal trigger, it completed in the normal amount of time. If you're seeing similar symptoms or it may be that like mine yours are a result of using the Debug options ... or perhaps you've enabled some diagnostics within Azure that have a similar effect.

No promises that this will fix your issue, but I thought I'd put this out there in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: I'm not at the same project anymore. And that project switched to AirFlow. So can't check this out. Great to hear you fixed it and when I'll have this issue at a later moment I'll remember this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the similar issue in ADF, where my TSQL procedure is overrunning for more than 4 hours than 2 hours normal completion time during run in SSMS.

As a workaround I split the Procedure into sequence of sub procedure and calling the master procedure to mitigate the slowness.
I tried to do the troubleshooting from Query Store in SSMS, but did not get much help from it to find the root cause.